# Image iconization using React Quill Using Java JPA

Tags: reactjs, spring, image, jpa, react-quill

I encountered a problem using React Quill Editor.

My current React code looks like this.

```
  const imageHandler = async () => {

  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
  input.click();

  input.addEventListener('change', async () => {
    const file = input.files[0];

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', file);

      // Send an image upload request to the server and receive the image URL.
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8090/images/upload', formData);
      const imageUrl = response.data.imageUrl;

      console.log("urlll", imageUrl)


      // 에디터에 이미지를 삽입합니다. 이미지 URL을 절대 경로로 설정합니다.
      const editor = contentRef.current.getEditor();
      const range = editor.getSelection();
      editor.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', `${imageUrl}`);
      editor.setSelection(range.index + 1);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
    }
  });
};



  const formats = [
    'header',
    'font',
    'size',
    'bold',
    'italic',
    'underline',
    'strike',
    'align',
    'blockquote',
    'list',
    'bullet',
    'indent',
    'background',
    'color',
    'link',
    'image',
    'video',
    'width',
  ];


  const modules = useMemo(() => {
return {
  toolbar: {
    container: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, 3, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
      ['blockquote'],
      [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
      [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
      [{ align: [] }],
      ['image', 'link' , 'video']
    ],
    handlers: {
      image: imageHandler,
    },
  },
};
}, []);

return(
  <ReactQuill
   ref = {contentRef}
   value={content}
   onChange={handleContentChange}
   modules={modules}
   formats={formats}
   placeholder={'write your board!'}
   theme="snow"
   />
);
```

The back-end code is like this. (Java JPA)

ImageController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/images")
public class ImageController {
@Autowired
private ImageUploadService imageUploadService;

@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> uploadImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) {
    try {
        // 이미지 업로드 및 이미지 URL 반환
        String imageUrl = imageUploadService.uploadImage(image);
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("imageUrl", imageUrl);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
}
```

ImageService

```
@Service
public class ImageUploadService {
@Value("${image.upload.directory}")
private String uploadDirectory; // 이미지 업로드 디렉토리 설정

public String uploadImage(MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
    // 이미지 업로드 처리
    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-" + image.getOriginalFilename();
    String filePath = Paths.get(uploadDirectory, fileName).toString();
    Files.copy(image.getInputStream(), Paths.get(filePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    // 이미지 URL 반환 ("/images/upload/파일명.jpg")
    return "/images/upload/" + fileName;
}
}
```

application.properties에는 파일 경로를 D드라이브에 폴더로 설정해줬습니다.

```
# 이미지 업로드 디렉토리 설정
image.upload.directory=D:/imagestest/upload
```

problem

1. The file is saved fine in that upload directory.
   [image]
2. I displayed the url value in the log and it came out fine.
   [image]
3. But the problem is that the image is not displayed properly in ReactQuill, it is displayed in icon format.
   [image]
4. When I uploaded an image to ReactQuill before using imageHolder, it was applied as base64 and the image was displayed properly. However, after imageHolder and processing in the backend (saving the file on the server and loading it in url format), it is displayed like this.
   When using base64 to upload a post to the server, it will not be uploaded because it is too long.